# bash: best practice to iterate over directory content until condition matches

Tags: bash, loops, iteration

I have the following case:

I'd like to go over the files in a directory `$1` *until* one of them meets my condition.

In detail: I'd like to test the directory on whether it contains audio files. As soon as the first audio file is found, `process_audio_dir` should take place; if there are no audio files in the dir, `process_noaudio` will happen.

My solution so far:

```
if [[ -z $(file -b "$1"/* | grep -i audio) ]]; then
  echo "there are no audio files"; process_noaudio
else
  echo "at least one audio file"; process_audio_dir
fi
```

`file -b` tells me what filetype a file is.

My guess from looking at it with `set -x` is, that this will run `file -b` on all the files, puts the result in one line and greps that line for a match. (Maybe that's a wrong assumption).

I'd rather have a loop that goes until it finds the first audio file (one is enough to match the condition) and stops/breaks there or, if there are no audio files, goes on to `process_noaudio`.

I have the feeling that while/until would be the thing to achieve this, but I can't figure it out.

What would be (your preferred|best practice|most elegant|least costly|fastest) method to check each file in a directory up to the first match?

Comment: thought I did, but I removed the (additional) code tags. guess this was an automated comment?

Comment: Thank you. The code is so better to read.

Comment: Which platform? If we only need to support GNU `file`, this can be done in a manner that sacrifices neither efficiency nor correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the safest way would be to iterate over the glob results directly, so you aren't vulnerable to the filenames containing special characters:

```
for path in "$1"/*; do
    if file -b -- "$path" | grep -qi audio; then
        printf 'Found an audio file %s\n' "$path"
        process_audio_dir
        exit
   fi
done
# since we didn't exit above, most be no audio files
printf "Didn't find any audio files\n"
process_noaudio
```

Alternately, if you don't want to exit there, you could set a flag indicating that you found it and check that after the loop, and just use a `break` inside the `if` to exit the loop once you've found one.

The reason yours is applying `grep` to the output of all the `file` results, is that the glob expands first so you then run the command, for example

```
file -b dir/file1 dir/file2 dir/file3 ...
```

then the output of that command will be fed to `grep`  My solution puts the glob on the "outside" of the command, so we'll just run it on each file individually.  Of course, there's more overhead with launching `file` lots of times, so it's not obvious to me right away which is going to be more efficient.  It'll probably depend on how many files there are, how far down the list the first audio file usually is and stuff like that.

As has been mentioned in the comments, it's dangerous to iterate over the printed filename results from `find` or `ls`, since those results would be subject to word splitting and potentially globbing depending on how exactly you do it.  Using the `for` loop above is the recommended way to do it generally.  For more see [Don't Parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Hi Eric; yes, that's the point I was aiming at. I could do a for loop with maybe `for each_file in $(find "$1" -type f); do file -b $each_file | grep -i audio; if [matches audio file] do x; continue; else do y; continue; fi` or something. I was wondering what the "standard" or most efficient way would be?

Comment: @badlands, using a `for` loop to iterate over `find` output in that way is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), entry #1.

Comment: BTW -- why "Assuming you don't have too many files in the directory"? `for` loops aren't subject to the argv length limit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, I actually wasn't sure about that part, so thanks for the fix, I'll update now!

Comment: The only thing that strikes me as still messing this up is the case where the directory named in `$1` starts with a dash -- unlikely, but possible; passing `--` before expanding `"$path"` will fix that. Otherwise, the only objections I can find are efficiency-related (running `file` once per file), and avoiding those without sacrificing correctness requires GNUisms.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks once more for the `--` tip.  I share the concern about the many invocations of `file`, but I think your answer highlights the hoops one must use to address that.  Also, we then get into the opinion side of "best" of course

Comment: Absolutely. I think we both have good answers, and the OP could rightly choose either.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy this is a very good link. In fact, I've used most all of the mentioned pitfalls in my 100+ line audio-sanitizer script, i.e. it starts with IFS='

Comment: @badlands That whole site is worth many iterations of reading!

Comment: @ Charles Duffy this is a very good link. In fact, I've used most all of the mentioned pitfalls in my 100+ line audio-sanitizer script, i.e. it starts with IFS=' (can't do a literal newline here)'. OK so afais a "for" loop over "$1"/* would be the way to go. I'm not much of a programmer as you see. Maybe just influenced by natural language I was wondering whether a "while" or "until" loop would be the "right" way. So `for file in $1/*; do` will actually check every file one after another and exit the loop (if conditional command says it should). I'll try a corrected version tomorrow ;). Thanks

Comment: @badlands for this task I think the `for` is the way to go myself.  Be sure to put quotes around your `$1` there though, so if there is a space in the directory name, for example, it will still work correctly

Comment: Thanks for clarification everybody :). Marked this as the right solution, since it is closest to what I had in mind. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

#### Inefficient, but compatible

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f \
  -exec sh -c 'file -b -- "$1" | grep -qi audio' _ {} \; \
  -print \
  -quit
```

Here, we're executing a shell pipeline running `file` on each individual name, then invoking `grep` to check its result. This is obviously inefficient, but since the `-exec` fails when the shell command it runs returns a nonzero exit code, `find` still will exit early on the first result where `grep` returns a truthy value (and thus allows the `-print` and `-quit` actions to run).

---

#### Efficient, but GNU-only

```
shopt -s nocaseglob # enable case-insensitive matching
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename && IFS= read -r type; do
  if [[ $type = *audio* ]]; then
    break # exit the loop with the name in "$filename" and the type in "$type"
  fi
done < <(find "$1" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec file -b -0 -- '{}' +)
echo "Found file $filename of type $type"
```

Here, we're running as few `file` instances as possible (using `-exec ... {} +` to pass multiple filenames to each `file` invocation), using the GNU extension `-0` to print a NUL after each filename in their output. This output is then parsed with a pair of `read` commands, and the type is checked for the substring `audio`.

Comment: `-maxdepth` should be specified before `-type` and other non-option arguments. Also missing a line continuation in the first example.

Comment: Thank you; amended.

Comment: Charles, +1, but a short circuit perhaps appropriate here for brevity: `[[ $type = *audio* ]] && break`

Answer (score 0):

In the POSIX C API we have [opendir()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir)/[readdir()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) which is the most flexible way to read the contents of a directory incrementally as a stream. There is no such mapping of these functions to Bash though.

`ls` is the cardinal way you list the contents of directories in Bash. You can do something like the following with `ls` to process the listing as a stream (but I'm pretty sure if `ls` will buffer up the listing. `ls` does support sorting which would entail buffering up):

```
ls "$1" | while read f; do test -f $f && echo $f | grep -q "audio" && echo $f && break; done
```

Another common tool is `find`. Find works incrementally. The following will work for your use case of "iterating over directory content until condition matches" and is a better approach than `ls`. This just prints the first found file name. Adjust to suite exactly what you want to do when the condition matches:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec "bash" -c "file -b '{}' | grep -qi audio" ";" -print -quit
```

Comment: The advice given here is actively harmful: Using `ls` output programmatically [is an antipattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), as its format is not sufficiently well-specified as to accurately represent all filenames in a manner which can be reliably reversed to their literal contents (thus, in a manner usable by `open()`-type calls). For similar reasons, automated usage of `find` should use `-print0` to emit even names with newline literals in unambiguous form.

Comment: Also, the OP's condition requires running `file`; thus, a `-name` match is insufficient.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was showing options on how to process `ls` output as a stream, since the OP uses it in his post. My advice is to use find.

Comment: Gotcha. I still read this as testing the name rather than the type metadata as determined by `file -b`, though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy regarding `file -b`: The OPs question is "best practice to iterate over directory content until condition matches". The solution is general jist and can be easily adjusted to suite.

Comment: Certainly, but there's domain knowledge about *how* to adjust it. It's easy for you or for me, but that's why we're writing answers; it's not obvious to everyone, for instance, that `-exec ... {} \;` will count as a failed test clause (preventing further actions from being run) when what it runs returns nonzero.

Comment: Yes I suppose. On the other hand I don't like to confound the essence of the answer behind specifics. I updated my answer to show an `-exec`

Comment: hm, this looks good and simple, but/although I don't fully understand it; `find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec "bash" -c 'file -b "{}" | grep -qi audio' ";" -print -quit` so up to `type f` it will find a file, the `exec` will start a shell wich runs `-c` command `file -b` on the first result `{}` which will be grepped for a match "audio". But how does the conditional part work? I checked the line on some dirs, and indeed it works fine ;) but I don't understand the conditional in it.

Comment: @badlands. Not sure what your asking, but: The way find works is you have a sequence of tests and actions. For each file, find runs the tests from left to right until one fails (by default). The result of the `-exec` test is the return value of the cmd. So in this case, if the command `file -b {} | grep -qi "audio"` returns 0, find continues and executes -print (which always returns true), then -quit which terminates the find. If your asking how to use this in a conditional; you can use it like this: `[[ -n $(...) ]] && echo "Found audio" || echo "No audio found"` where `...` is the find cmd.

Comment: `-exec "bash" -c 'file -b "{}" | grep -qi audio' ";"` is prone to injection attacks -- filenames containing content expanded as code. This is an exploitable security bug if filenames in the directory in question can be controlled by someone other than yourself.

Comment: ...to avoid such attacks, keep data out-of-band from code; in this case, that means expanding the argument outside of script text: `-exec bash -c 'file -b "$1" | grep -qi audio' _ {} ";"`

Comment: Ah true, or use single quotes instead which is a little more readable. Thx updated.

Comment: @S.Pinkus, single-quotes aren't adequate to task, because a filename can contain single-quote literals and thus escape them. Consider the effect of running this on a directory containing the file created by `touch $'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\''` -- the first one activates if content isn't single-quoted, the latter one activates if it is.

Comment: Oh yeah... I concur. Thx for the schooling today ;).

Comment: @S.Pinkus thanks for all the insight. I wasn't aware that the find command itself is already testing and only prints on successful match (of when thinking about it, it's ovious). I find this solution good and interesting, too, but marked the one above as "correct" since it's somewhat closer to my initial approach (and seems to be a tad faster, not that it matters much in my case). Thanks for the insight and time! Cheers

Comment: No worries mate :)